# Run the files in the order - Java file - invokes shell file invokes java file-

Tags: java, shell, terminal

I'm working on a project in which I run a java file using Terminal. That file should invoke a shell script. The script, in turn, runs a java file with user input on Terminal.  I used the following code to do the same:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run.sh");
```

But the terminal does not ask for user input and the program terminates.
The second file is a continuous process and could be run multiple times thus can't give console input to that process.

Please help me to achieve the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to store exec to a Process, then use the InputStream on the process to give him the file. Also use its outputtteam to see the programm situation

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50432304).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using inputStream and OutputStream to read and write data to a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432304/using-inputstream-and-outputstream-to-read-and-write-data-to-a-process)

Comment: The following solution did not work for me exactly as I wanted. It did run the java file, but the point where it should ask for user input is being skipped. I believe it is because System.consol is turning out to be null. Please help me out.